# Different Model callbacks depending on whether for API or in-app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, model, callback

I want to add a mobile app to my web app that has some differences in the User model. Specifically when a User signs up in the web app, the model generates an activation digest which is emailed to them to click on. The callback is:

```
# app/models/user.rb
before_create :create_activation_digest
```

I will use a different Users_controller for the api that has an api namespace. When a new user registers from the mobile app I don't want to create the activation digest, but instead generate an access token.

```
# app/models/user.rb
before_create :generate_access_token
```

So what is the best way to run the first if it is an in-app signup and the second if it is a mobile app signup. Do I call the method from the controller instead of a model callback? Or is there a better way in the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, avoid model callbacks at all costs. They are difficult to skip, a bit difficult to test, difficult to customize depending on context.

I would consider creating user factories classes and calling them in your controllers, you can easily pass context and do any other customization needed.

Edit since I haven't really given you a way to do that.

If you really want to achieve that with callbacks, probably the only way to do it is to define a new attribute in your user model (not backed by a database field), e.g.

```
attr_accessor :created_from_api
```

setting that attribute in your controller and then customizing your model callbacks, e.g.

```
before_create :create_activation_digest, unless: :created_from_api
```

This should work, but if I were in your place, I really would move away from callbacks.

Comment: So define the attribute in attr_accessor and in the api/users_controller do something like: @user.created_from_api = true. Seems like that would work.

Comment: Okay, I confirmed that works. I have not had bad luck with model callbacks but I'll keep your comment in mind in case I start running into trouble with them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that creating and activation digest and generating an access token do not belong in the `User` model - that seems like too much responsibility for `User`.

Personally, I would say the same thing for the controllers.

So, I would suggest that you use a service object.

Comment: That's probably a good suggestion but not my personal preference in terms of structure. I try to fit as much as I can in a model, view (or helper), or controller.

Comment: Fair enough. In my world, I put almost nothing in models, views, and controllers - they are all excruciatingly skinny. My models typically have only associations and validations. Views never include any logic and no access to models. And controller actions are always one line long (and there are only two variations of the lines that show up in actions). But, mine is a strange little world.